# CSS horizontal strip background in boxed page

Tags: html, css

i've  got quite a problem with css. Is there any "fast" way to add  horizontal background under  "div stripe" on WHOLE page width? I have some  important content and i want  highlight it.

My page code looks like:

```
<body>
<div wrapper width=1200px>
<div content>
<some h1>
<some boxes>
<div stripe>
     //some important stuff what i want highlight
</div>
</div>
</div >
</body>
```

Kind regards 
mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body>
<div id = ' wrapper' style = " width=1200px">
<div id='content'>

<div id='stripe'>
     //some important stuff what i want highlight
</div>
</div>
</div >
</body>
```

For the above HTML added the following CSS

```
#stripe{
    background-color:red;
}
```

through the id a color or image can be assign under the div.

[The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmfbvgwq/)

Comment: oh sorry i've used  wrong word.  On whole  body (not page only).  For example  if  site  width is  1200px and i have bigger screen 1600 i will have  white stripe on left and right. I want put there  background on  div strip height.

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo-element works best here I think.

You can use colors or even background images on it...and this one is responsive too.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container div {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.stripe {
  position: relative;
}
.stripe::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div class="stripe"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```